# could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'

Tags: gradle

To study Gradle I am using the book `Gradle in action`. 
There was an example of dependency definition.

```
dependencies {
      compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.1'
}
```

But when I do in console `gradle build` I've got an error
[image]

What is the problem? My whole `.gradle` file looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
     compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did not tell Gradle where to find commons-lang3 library. Easy fix is to add the following to your build script:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Of course you can find this piece of information in documentation - http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N10608

Comment: I already have `repositories { mavenCentral() }` in my `build.gradle`. What could it be in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue. I fixed it by using local gradle distribution instead of the default gradle wrapper. This is how it goes, make sure that you have Gradle installed and setup(PATH variable).

Open IntelliJ. Goto File->setting->Build, Exec, Deployment->Build tools->Gradle and use local gradle distribution and add your Gradle Home. Apply changes and try to run it now.